# Positioning AJAX ModalPopupExtender in the center of the screen problem

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I have problem with positioning ModalPopupExtender in the center of the screen when it's PopupDragHandleControlID property is set (without this property it works fine ).

ModalPopupExtender is not positioned in the center of the screen.
I thinks what causes the problem is the page's CSS layout cause when i disable it, popup positioned in the center of the screen (I don't understand why page's css affects ModalPopupExtender only when it's PopupDragHandleControlID property is set  )

Thepage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <div id="header">
    </div>

     <div id="container">
       <div id="center" class="column">                    

          <div id="centercolcontent" class="centercolcontent">    
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>


        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server" Text="Open" />   
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlUploader" runat="server" CssClass="pnlUploader"   style="display: none;">
                    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlPopup1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup"
                                PopupControlID="pnlUploader" CancelControlID="btnCancel"
                                BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
                                PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlUploader" RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResize"   />
                    <div id="pnlDragMe" class="pnlDragMe">
                        Image Uploader
                     </div>     

                     <div class="upload" id="upload">             
                         <div id="status" class="info">
                           Please select a file to upload
                         </div>
                        <div class="commands">      
                         <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server"  Text="Upload" 
                             OnClientClick="javascript:onUploadClick()" />
                         <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
                      </div>        
                   </div>                                      
                </asp:Panel>    

            </ContentTemplate>   
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
          </div>

       </div>

      </div>               
      <div id="left" class="column">
      </div>

      <div id="right" class="column">                        
      </div>          

    <div id="footer">

    </div>




    </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

The CSS:

```
body
{
    min-width: 630px; 
}

#container
{
    padding-left: 200px; 
    padding-right: 150px; 
}

#container .column
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

#center
{
    padding: 0px 0px; 
    width: 100%;
}

#left
{
    width: 200px; 
    padding: 0 0px 0 0; 
    right: 200px;
    margin-left: -100%;
}

#right
{
    width: 130px;
    padding: 0 10px; 
    margin-right: -100%;
}

#footer
{
    clear: both;
}


* html #left
{
    left: 150px; /* RC fullwidth */
}

/*** Equal-height Columns ***/

#container
{
    overflow: hidden;
}

#container .column
{
    padding-bottom: 1001em; /* X + padding-bottom */
    margin-bottom: -1000em; /* X */
}



* html body
{
    overflow: hidden;
}

* html #footer-wrapper
{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 10010px;
    margin-bottom: -10000px;
    background: #FFF; /*** Same as body background ***/
}



body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#header, #footer
{
    font-size: large;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0.3em 0;
}

#left
{
    /*background: #66F;*/
}

#center
{
    background: #DDD;
}



.modalBackground
{
    background-color: Gray;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Modal popup panel is given an **absolute** position. So it needs to be inside an element which has a **non-static position**. In this case, I want it to be centred on the page, so I have put it inside an element (in this case an UpdatePanel but it doesn't matter what kind of element it is) which has an inline style of **position:fixed;left:0;top:0**.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updProductPopup" runat="server" style="position:fixed;left:0;top:0;">
<contenttemplate>

    <act:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeProduct" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="modalPopupBackground" BehaviorID="behaviourModalPopup" OkControlID="btnMpClose" PopupControlID="pnlModalPopup" PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlMpHandle" TargetControlID="btnMpHidden">
    </act:ModalPopupExtender>

    <!-- pnlModalPopup MUST have inline style display:none -->
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlModalPopup" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" style="display:none;">
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlMpHandle" CssClass="modalPopupDragHandle">
            Panel Header
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlMpContent">Here's my content</asp:Panel>
        <p class="modalPopupClose">
            <a id="btnMpClose" href="#" class="custom-button">Close</a>
        </p>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Button ID="btnMpHidden" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="modalPopupHiddenButton" />

</contenttemplate>
```

I know the original question is quite old, but I spent a lot of time looking for the answer to this problem without finding it, and this question is comes up quite highly on Google, so hopefully this will save someone else some time.

Comment: Awesome solution! solved for me (I used a div instead of UpdatePanel)

Comment: Thanks for this one! Works perfect! This answer should be marked as solved!

Comment: awesome. still work like magic. however, updatepanel didn't do a vertical-center for me, I ended up using a div.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I hope OP someday marks this as the answer. Here's what I did with this solution: a div with a class, right after the "form" and Ajax ToolkitScriptManager tags, with the styles "display: block; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 500;". Change the z-index do anything higher than your other page elements, but lower than your modal message styles.

Answer (score 6):

Use the x and y attributes of the ModalPopupExtender.

Comment: The x and y solution worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but no answer yet ... so its ok?

Anyway ... make sure the panel is separated from the main page div/panel.  It's using that as the window to set position.

Answer (score 1):

The `ModalPopupExtender` shows the `Panel` given as `PopupControlId` centered inside the div you declared the `Panel`. So try keeping the `ModalPopupExtender` where you defined it, and moving out the popup `Panel` from its containers (even out of the `UpdatePanel`). It works for me.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a very old question, but as also got here looking for a solution, I thought I may post how I finally solved the issue, to help others.

Just use that style in your panel:

```
<asp:Panel style="left: 50% !important; top: 10% !important; display: none;" />
```

The "important" clause will override all other settings from the modalpopupextender. The percentages are taken from twitter bootstrap as a standard.
"display" also will prevent your panel to show while loading the page.

Answer (score 0):

This took me frickin ages to work out for my case, but in the end all I had to do was to change the height of the panel I was extending from 100% to a fixed height bigger than the panel.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlUploader" Width="500px"...
```

I also had my extender outside the panel but doubt if that matters. AjaxControlToolkit not a favourite!

Answer (score 0):

```
#ModalPopUp
 {
    Position:relative;
    Height:400px;
    Width:400px;
    Margin-left:auto;
    Margin-right:auto;
  }
```

This should position your popup in the center of your page. Then just set the CSS for the modalbackground and you should be fine.

Tom

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it's working great.
The spot you looking for is X="100" Y="100". It give fixed position and the popupDragHandleControlID give you the possibility to drag your window as you wish.
Here the solution

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpePopupTestAdd" runat="server" TargetControlID="hfdPopupAnchorTestAdd" PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlPopupTestAdd"  X="100" Y="100" PopupControlID="pnlPopupFilterAdd" CancelControlID="btnCancelFilterAdd" BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG"></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlPopupTestAdd" Style="display: none" runat="server" Width="550" DefaultButton="btnOKTestAdd">
    <div id="divContainerTestAdd" runat="server" class="panel Test">
<!-- header-->
<!-- Body -->
        </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13248911/684617), the placement of the `<asp:Panel>` (or whatever container used to house the modal's contents) within the page is important.  If you are experiencing display issues and your modal's container is nested within a bunch of other tags (especially tags that alter the layout), try moving it out of those other tags.

You will probably not be able to put your modal as the first child within the `<body>` because of the need to place it following the `<asp:ScriptManager>`, which itself needs to be within a `<form>`.  You may also need to use an `<asp:UpdatePanel>` if your modal features dynamic content.  In any case, the less "interference" you have from layout-altering tags, the less chance there is of something throwing off the fragile behind-the-scenes styling applied by the `ModalPopupExtender`.  [See this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2008/launch/cutting-edge-modal-dialog-boxes-with-ajax), particularly the code snippet in [Figure 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2008/launch/cutting-edge-modal-dialog-boxes-with-ajax#figure1details-of-the-modalpopupextender-control) for some insight into what `ModalPopupExtender` is doing behind the scenes to make these modals work.

In summary, try the following kind of placement (using some of the snippets from the OP's code):

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

        <asp:Panel ID="pnlUploader" runat="server" CssClass="pnlUploader" style="display: none;">
            <div id="pnlDragMe" class="pnlDragMe">Image Uploader</div> 

            <%-- Other content for this modal goes here... --%>
        </asp:Panel>

        <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlPopup1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup"
                                PopupControlID="pnlUploader" CancelControlID="btnCancel"
                                BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
                                PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlUploader"
                                RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResize" />

       <%-- Additional modals can be defined here... --%>

       <%-- After all modals are defined, add the page content... --%>

    </form>
</body>
```

If defining the modal as high up on the page as possible is still not working, try excluding some or all of your included `.css` or `<style>` declarations, especially if you have any that are very generically applied (e.g. to all `<div>` tags, or the `<body>` tag).  Alternatively, try inspecting the page with your browser's developer tools.  Consider finding where the modal is and tracing up from there.  Look at each containing tag and inspect each one's styles, selectively disabling them to see if doing so improves the modal's positioning.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this can be achieved by two ways.

- Write a css class property like below
  and call the class name in the
  ModalPopupExtender.

CSS:

```
.hcenter{margin:0 auto; width:200;} /* I have given a sample width you give the width of your popup */
```

CODE :

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlUploader" runat="server" CssClass="hcenter"   style="display: none;">
  <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mdlPopup1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup"
        PopupControlID="pnlUploader" CancelControlID="btnCancel"
        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"
        PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlUploader"
        RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResize"   />
```

...

- Try HorizontalOffset property in
  panel.

Comment: it didn't help.
And there is only HorizontalAlign property and it's for panel's content.

Answer (score -1):

```
.panel 
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
}


<asp:Panel id ="pnlUploader" CssClass="panel">
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove Parameter x, y and repositio nmode by default it takes center position also when you scroll.